# Write an NSMutableArray to a file and load it back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, file-io, nsmutablearray

I'm doing some exercises about writing to and loading from a file.

I've created an `NSString`, then written it to a file, and then loaded an `NSString` again. Simple.

How can I do this with an `NSMutableArray` of `NSStrings`, or better an `NSMutableArray` of my own class?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...

        //write a NSString to a file
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

        NSString *str = @"hello world";
        NSArray *myarray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ola",@"alo",@"hello",@"hola", nil];

        [str writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        //load NSString from a file
        NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
        NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        NSLog(@"str2: %@",str2);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Printed: str2: hello world

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to write your array as a plist, you can

```
// save it

NSArray *myarray = @[@"ola",@"alo",@"hello",@"hola"];
BOOL success = [myarray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSAssert(success, @"writeToFile failed");

// load it

NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSAssert(array2, @"arrayWithContentsOfFile failed");
```

For more information, see [Using Objective-C Methods to Read and Write Property-List Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW3) in the *Property List Programming Guide.*

But, f you want to preserve the mutability/immutability (i.e. the precise object types) of your objects, as well as open up the possibility of saving a wider array of object types, you might want to use an archive rather than a plist:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello world"];
NSMutableArray *myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:str, @"alo", @"hello", @"hola", nil];

//save it

BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myarray toFile:path];
NSAssert(success, @"archiveRootObject failed");

//load NSString from a file

NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
NSAssert(array2, @"unarchiveObjectWithFile failed");
```

While I illustrate the technique with an array, it works with any object that conforms to  [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (which includes many of the basic Cocoa classes like strings, arrays, dictionaries, `NSNumber`, etc.). If you want to make your own classes work with `NSKeyedArchiver`, then you must make them conform to `NSCoding`, too. For more information, see the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Answer (score 0):

[This document at Apple walks you through the process.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html)

Comment: Thank you. I still prefer a simple example. but I promise I'm going to read it.

Comment: The first listing on that page does provide a simple example. Otherwise I would not have linked it.