# How to load/save data in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, appdelegate

Here is my `mainAppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end
```

and my `mainAppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "mainAppDelegate.h"

@implementation mainAppDelegate

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];
    [self.toDoItems writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
}
@end
```

I have another file, `XYZToDoListViewController.m` with the code:

```
#import "XYZToDoListViewController.h"
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"
#import "XYZAddItemViewController.h"

@interface XYZToDoListViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
@end

@implementation XYZToDoListViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    XYZAddItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (IBAction)clearData:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
{
    [self.toDoItems removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor =
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_full.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, -35, 0);
}
@end
```

This is at least what I think is relevant. My basic framework is something I followed from [this tutorial.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1) So as you can see I have an NSMutableArray named .toDoItems. and I want it to remember the list when I exit the application (not just minimizing it; it does that already. I think I have the code which is saving the data, but what do I use to check if the file exists, and if so, display it?
And would this affect my `clearData` method when the app resumes as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a NSMutableArray to a file and load it back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594670/write-a-nsmutablearray-to-a-file-and-load-the-nsmutablearray-from-a-file-comman)

Comment: Are XYZToDoItem very complex (I mean a lot of custom objects nested in it) ? You can save it in [NSUserDefault](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) aswell

Comment: I'm not sure I see an answer in this question that I can get working. I'll check out the apple walkthroughs that are posted.
@HaneTV They're not; just user inputted text values. I tried messing with the UserDefault route as well but I'm not sure i understood how that worked.

Comment: the tutorial I linked is pretty straightforward if you don't want/need to save files :)

Comment: @HaneTV Ok... so I have the `NSKeyedArchiver` in my `applicationWillTerminate` method and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` in my `viewDidLoad` method. Is this correct? Also what are the `Keys` referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if i understood true you want to save your NSMutableArray even after restart your app.
So you may use this codes to save your NSMutableArray with NSUserDefaults.

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultsPhoneId setObject:yourArray forKey:@"yourKey"];
[defaultsPhoneId synchronize];
```

And it is how you can take it back

```
yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"yourKey"]];
```

But dont forget to initialize it before save with NSUserDefaults.
By the way you may check yourArray anytime if it is loaded or not with

```
if([yourArray count]==0){
 //Your array is empty so you have to call it with @"yourKey". (second codes part)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This finally worked for me once I figured out where to place the code and what typos I had been making.

Answer (score 0):

"what do I use to check if the file exists"

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:your_file_path])
```

"..and if so, display it?"

> Please read about UITableView and UITableViewDataSource
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

"And would this affect my clearData method when the app resumes as well?"

**clearData is a button action. It will be called only if user will tap
 a button. It is not connected with application launch/stopping.**

Comment: My thought about clearData was this: the phone has a stored list on there, and the user quits, so the information is saved. When the application reopens, the user clears the data and then exits the application again. Would this redisplay the last saved data?

Comment: So trying to follow this logic I've simply added: `NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"toDoItems.plist"])
    {
       self.toDoItems = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"toDoItems.plist"] init];
    } else{
      self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }` to my `viewDidLoad` method but to no avail....

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand you. Here '[self.toDoItems removeAllObjects];' you are cleaning only run-time array. File is not affected.